PTERA Aircraft Technical data report
Where can I access data recorded by the Prototype Technology evaluation and research Aircraft or PTERA? I have scoured the NASA technical server but all there is available is details on the project and stability data but none on the aerodynamic efficiency recorded.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What makes you think data on aerodynamic efficiency was taken?  The experiment was mostly about stability effects.  Measuring drag in-flight is notoriously challenging.

One of the objectives was validating the aerodynamic efficiency of morphing control surfaces/wings. so, I imagine there would be data recorded on this.
